# Codeception: how to define different config log directories and switch under different test environments?

Tags: testing, logging, automated-tests, codeception

I want to run tests in different browsers, environments and compare the reports and screenshots. Because of the default in codeception, the test reports and logs will be stored into one output directory which is specified in *log*, like `log:tests/_output`.

How can I specify a different path for different environment output without changing the codeception configuration codes, for instance, if I run the tests in chrome and firefox, then I get the two directories `log:tests/_output/firefox` for test results with firefox and `log:tests/_output/chrome` for chrome.

It is possible to define different config log directories and switch it through command line, just like switch the test environments by using option `--env`?

Comment: Which version of codeception do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you can overwrite the "path" variables in the environment files (_env) with the generate:environment command. It seems, you can only overrule modules config.